# Deleting files opened within a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm currently working on a JavaFX application that uses a save file to load information about the previous session. I am having problems closing my BufferedReader and BufferedWriters. Files are not being unlocked until the JavaFX application is terminated. I have traced through the code and to ensure that there are no BufferedReaders and BufferedWriters left un-closed. If I try to modify the files after JavaFX is closed, they will be renamed and deleted correctly. Here's an example of one of my methods for reading and writing to files.

This is a school assignment and external libraries are not allowed.

```
public static boolean addNewAccount(User user, String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        File output = new File("temp.csv");
        File input = new File(fileName);


        if (output.exists())
        {
            output.delete();
            output.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output.getName()));
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input.getName()));

        ...
        Read and write stuff here.
        ...

        inputStream.close();
        inputStream = null;
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;
        System.gc();

        input.delete();
        if (!output.renameTo(input))
        {
            HistoryLog.getInstance().log("Something is preventing a file from being closed.");
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple problems here. Your I/O streams should close in `finally`. `FileReader` and `FileWriter` are never closed. Try to use `try..with..resources` instead of traditional `try..catch..finally`.

Comment: The problem is that this code executes fine when its not being executed inside of JavaFX. FileReader and FileWriter should be closed when BufferedReader and BufferedWriter call their close methods.

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. Without a MCVE, it is very difficult to tell the concrete reason for the failure.

Comment: If you insist. I'm working on a new, really small JavaFx application for you to test it yourself.

Comment: Well i'm not going to lie. I'm having trouble reproducing it in a small file. Something, somewhere must be keeping the files open.

Comment: I fixed it, it was a problem with the file paths being passed incorrectly to the methods that read the files. The Readers and Writers were all being closed properly.

The file paths were accepted by FileWriter and FileReader, but File was having problems with them. Forcing me to do it in a small file gave me some good ideas for trying to fix the issue,

Comment: Great, may be this question doesn't need to exist anymore.